# Set kendo-grid-column class based on dataItem

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

In the kendo grid component for angular, how do I achieve something akin to the following?

```
<kendo-grid-column field="value" [class]={'danger': dataItem.value > 30}>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

I know I can put a template inside the kendo-grid-column and that template has access to the dataItem, but that only allows me to set a class on elements in the template and not on the td itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) like that:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="value" [ngClass]="(dataItem.value > 30) ? 'danger': ''">
</kendo-grid-column>
```